# Additional fields in Moodle custom auth method plugin

Tags: php, authentication, moodle

I have a custom authentication method plugin, I have added a custom form. The plugin works fine, but I need to add another field to the form and get the submitted value in the `user_login` function

Username: [Field for the username]
Password: [field for the password]
Another text: [field for additional text]

Now in the `auth.php` and in the

```
function user_login($username, $password){
    ....
    ....
    ....
    //I want to be able to get the value of the submitted field (additional text field) here
}
```

How can I de that? Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use $_POST directly try

```
$fieldname = optional_param('field_name', null, PARAM_XXX);
```

or

```
$fieldname = required_param('field_name', PARAM_XXX);
```

Where PARAM_XXX is the type of value you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there would be something already defined as a function to get the values. Thank you!